# Programming a JButton to create an object when clicked

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton

EDIT: I want this window to be able to create multiple user profiles, so it needs to create more variables than just u1. The idea of the program is to mimic a social network. I don't know how to do this, however. Thanks!

I'm new to java GUI. So far, I have created a window with four text fields inside: first name, last name, gender, and hometown. I want to now create a button that takes the strings entered in those 4 text fields, and creates an object from them using this constructor:

```
//object constructor
public UserProfile(String fn, String ln, String g, String h) {
    firstName = fn;
    lastName = ln;
    fullName = fn + ' ' + ln;
    gender = g;
    homeTown = h;
}
```

Here is my CreateProfile class so far. The relevant code for the button is at the bottom, and I'm pretty sure it's wrong / inefficient.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

/* Window for creating a UserProfile */
public class CreateProfile extends JFrame {

    private JLabel jl1;
    public JTextField tf1;

    private JLabel jl2;
    public JTextField tf2;

    private JLabel jl3;
    public JTextField tf3;

    private JLabel jl4;
    public JTextField tf4;

    public JButton jb;

    public CreateProfile() {   // constructor for the window
        super("Create Your FaceSpace Profile");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        jl1 = new JLabel("First name: ");
        tf1 = new JTextField(null, 10);
        add(jl1);add(tf1);

        jl2 = new JLabel("Last name: ");
        tf2 = new JTextField(null, 10);
        add(jl2);add(tf2);

        jl3 = new JLabel("Gender (M/F): "); // make drop down
        tf3 = new JTextField(null, 10);
        add(jl3);add(tf3);

        jl4 = new JLabel("Hometown: ");
        tf4 = new JTextField(null, 10);
        add(jl4);add(tf4);

        /* Button that creates a UserProfile object given the four text fields */
        jb = new JButton("Create Profile!");
        add(jb);
        jb.addActionListener(this);

    }

    private class buttonEvent implements ActionListener {

        public void action(ActionEvent e) {
            String command = e.getActionCommand();
            if(command.equals("jb")) {
                // Code in question
                String fn = tf1.getText().trim();
                String ln = tf2.getText().trim();
                String g = tf3.getText().trim();
                String ht = tf4.getText().trim();
                UserProfile u1 = new UserProfile(fn,ln,g,ht);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What makes you says it's wrong? Does it work?

Comment: Do you get any exception?

Comment: What is exactly wrong? Does your button not work when clicked?

Comment: Well, I would like this to be able to create multiple profiles, not just u1. I don't know how to do this though. Since I'm also a GUI newbie, I don't exactly know how to test anything :/

Comment: Every answer creates a LOCAL `UserProfile` when the button is clicked. Modify any of these `actionPerformed` method and replace the local `UserProfile` with a global one.  How do you expect to use the user profile if the scope is local? Once the method execution concludes, the profile will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your class CreateProfile doesn't implement the ActionListener so you can't use

```
jb.addActionListener(this);
```

You have to make new object your private class which implement ActionListener for example:

```
jb.addActionListener(new buttonEvent());
```

Additionaly class buttonEvent should implement actionPerformed instead of action method and the getActionCommand() returns button's title instead of "jb".

Your buttonEvent should look like:

```
private class buttonEvent implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if(command.equals("Create Profile!")) {
          String fn = tf1.getText().trim();
          String ln = tf2.getText().trim();
          String g = tf3.getText().trim();
          String ht = tf4.getText().trim();
          UserProfile u1 = new UserProfile(fn,ln,g,ht);
        }
    }

}
```

And don't forget about show your window using setVisible(true) in CreateProfile constructor.

EDIT:
If you want to have multiple user profiles you can make list and add new objects to that list.
For example in CreateProfile class add:

```
List<UserProfile> users = new ArrayList<UserProfile>();
```

and add new users

```
users.add(new UserProfile(fn,ln,g,ht));
```

instead of UserProfile u1 = new UserProfile(fn,ln,g,ht); in buttonEvent.

Comment: How can I have this method create multiple UserProfiles, u2 u3 u4, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can try make a "create" method:

```
private UserProfile createUserProfile() {
    String fn = tf1.getText().trim();
    String ln = tf2.getText().trim();
    String g = tf3.getText().trim();
    String ht = tf4.getText().trim();

    return new UserProfile(fn,ln,g,ht);
}
```

And use it:

```
private class buttonEvent implements ActionListener {

    public void action(ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if(command.equals("jb")) {
            UserProfile u1 = createUserProfile();
        }
    }

}
```